# Bootstrap CSS not working on SSL

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ssl

About to switch my website that uses Bootstrap CSS to SSL, but when I look at the page on SSL the boostrap CSS formatting disappears.

This is it with Bootstrap CSS working (not SSL):

http://learntoberich.com/schedule/

And this is it with Boostrap CSS not working (on SSL):

https://learntoberich.com/schedule/

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. if your primary page is loaded over https, your resources has also to be loaded with https. See browser console for error about it.

So, fix the style sheet reference to use https not http. better yet, use relative URLs if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the http part all together and link it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//learntoberich.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/resources/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing Vladimir's post, I was able to look at the settings in the Bootstrap CSS plugin and turn on the Link to CDNJS libraries instead of using local ones and that worked.

[image: Use CDNJS]

Answer (score 1):

Example: Inside the script src="http..."

You should replace http to https to make the bootstrap work on HTTPS webservices, otherwise your host doesn't capture bootstrap script.